# Why do I get a 'not defined' error for DivisionCollection when it's clearly defined?

Tags: javascript

Why do I get a 'not defined' error for DivisionCollection when it's clearly defined?

```
DivisionRepository = {
    DivisionCollection: [], //Defined here

    GetNewDivisionId:  function() {
        var newDivisionId = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < DivisionCollection.length; i++) { //Pukes here
            if(DivisionCollection[i].DivisionId >= newDivisionId)
                newDivisionId = DivisionCollection[i].DivisionId + 1;
        }

        return newDivisionId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `this.` before `DivisionCollection`, you're out of scope.

Comment: That doesn't work. Just gives the error "Unexpected token ."

Comment: use this.DivisionCollection and not DivisionCollection

Comment: Got it, that works. Not sure who downvoted you or why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not a scope issue. Object properties aren't variables, they don't have scope.

Comment: Well, code from inside GetNewDivisionId can't scope the DivisionCollection without "this". In a way, "this" is acting like a teleSCOPE so DivisionCollection can be resolved. So, seems like scoping issue to me. You just gotta scope it out man.